# Problem with binding a SwiftData model property to a Toggle

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data, swiftui-foreach

I'm trying to display a checklist in SwiftUI which is stored in SwiftData:

```
@Model
class ChecklistItem: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var isChecked: Bool
    var sortOrder: Int
    
    init(title: String, isChecked: Bool, sortOrder: Int) {
        self.title = title
        self.isChecked = isChecked
        self.sortOrder = sortOrder
    }
}

@Model
class ChecklistModel: Identifiable, Hashable, ObservableObject {
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: ChecklistModel, rhs: ChecklistModel) -> Bool {
        return ObjectIdentifier(lhs) == ObjectIdentifier(rhs)
    }
    
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    @Relationship var items: [ChecklistItem]
    
    init(title: String, items: [ChecklistItem]) {
        self.title = title
        self.items = items
    }
}

ScrollView {
    ForEach(checklist.items.sorted(by: { $0.sortOrder < $1.sortOrder }), id: \.self) { item in

    //ForEach(checklist.items.sorted(by: {$0.sortOrder < $1.sortOrder}).indices, id: \.self) { index in
    //  let item = checklist.items[index]
    // if I do it this way, the items are not sorted in the correct order

    HStack {
        Toggle(item.title, isOn: item.$isChecked)
            .toggleStyle(CheckboxToggleStyle())
        Text("\(item.sortOrder)")
    }
}
```

But if I try it the uncommented way so that the sorting works correctly, I get this error:

`Initializer 'init(_:isOn:)' requires that 'Binding<Subject>' conform to 'StringProtocol'`

So what's the solution here? How can I sort these items correctly in the view and also bind the `Toggle` value to the model?

Comment: Note, the `@Model` macro conforms to `Observable` and should not be mixed up with `ObservableObject`, so remove that and also those `hash` and `==` stuff.
 Try using `@Bindable var item = item
 HStack {
     Toggle(item.title, isOn: $item.isChecked)
 ...}`

Comment: And you don’t need to conform to  Identifiable either since that is already done (and then you don’t need a specific id property either since you already have one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `checklist` is one `ChecklistModel`, try this approach using a `@Bindable` as shown in the example code, together with the updated `@Model class` without the `ObservableObject`.

Note, `@Model` macro makes the class conform to Observable, Hashable and Identifiable.

```
 ScrollView {
     ForEach(checklist.items.sorted(by: { $0.sortOrder < $1.sortOrder })) { item in
         @Bindable var item = item  // <-- here
         HStack {
             Toggle(item.title, isOn: $item.isChecked)  // <-- here
                 .toggleStyle(.automatic)
             Text("\(item.sortOrder)")
         }
     }
 }
 
 @Model
 class ChecklistItem {  // <-- here
     var title: String
     var isChecked: Bool
     var sortOrder: Int
     
     init(title: String, isChecked: Bool, sortOrder: Int) {
         self.title = title
         self.isChecked = isChecked
         self.sortOrder = sortOrder
     }
 }

 @Model
 class ChecklistModel {  // <-- here
     var title: String
     
     @Relationship var items: [ChecklistItem]
     
     init(title: String, items: [ChecklistItem]) {
         self.title = title
         self.items = items
     }
 }
```

See this link [SwiftData with model](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/preserving-your-apps-model-data-across-launches), it gives you some good examples of how to use `SwiftData` with `@Model` to
persist data in your app.

Comment: This is working great, thank you. I'm trying to understand something though. How does the line `@Bindable var item = item` work? Aren't you creating a copy of the `item`? How does it still get persisted in SwiftData when you change a copy of the item? Is it because of `@Bindable`?

Comment: `@Bindable` is
 "A property wrapper type that supports creating bindings to the mutable properties of observable objects". It is used in the code so you can change it in your
 `Toggle(item.title, isOn: $item.isChecked)`. It gets persisted in SwiftData automatically since you have `@Model`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
// ... your other code
   
 Toggle("\(item.title)", isOn: item.$isChecked)
    

// ... your other code
```