Getting Bundle Identifier on MenuBarExtra
I’m writing a MenuBarExtra which needs to know the current application. I have some code which nearly does the job:
import SwiftUI

@main
struct XBApp: App {
    @State var bundleID: String = ""

    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra("Something", systemImage: "questionmark.bubble") {
            VStack {
                XBContent(bundleID: bundleID)
                    .padding(0)
            }
            .onAppear {
                bundleID = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!.bundleIdentifier!
                print("\(#fileID):\(#line) - \(bundleID)")
            }
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
    }
}

struct XBContent: View {
    var bundleID: String = ""
    @State var data: String = ""

    init(bundleID: String) {
        self.bundleID = bundleID    //  store received value
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(bundleID)          //  current value
            Text(data)              //  previous value
        }
        .onAppear {
            data = bundleID         //  copy value
            print("\(#fileID):\(#line) - \(bundleID) | \(data)")
        }
    }
}

The main App sets the current Bundle id in .onAppear and this is then passed on to the XBContent view. I think this part is doing its job correctly, but I’m open to correction.
The XBContent view simply displays two versions of the passed bundle id:

the init() method stores the value in a property.
the onAppear copies it into another variable for testing. In real life, it’s supposed to use this value to read some other data.
the VStack displays the value from init() and the copied value from onAppear.

Here’s the problem: the copied value from onAppear is always one step behind the other. When the app is first launched, and the menu bar extra is opened, the first value is correct, while the second is the default empty string; this is fixed the next time. When I switch to another app and open the menu bar extra, the first value is the correct new bundle id, while the second is the old one, until I try it again and it’s OK.
I gather from this that onAppear is not triggered when I thought it should be.
How can I get the second value to be the correct one?

Try this approach using @Binding var bundleID: String. Note no need for the init(...) in XBContent, the view does it all for you. Tested on real device macOS 15.
@main
struct XBApp: App {
    @State private var bundleID: String = "" // <--- here

    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra("Something", systemImage: "questionmark.bubble") {
            VStack {
                XBContent(bundleID: $bundleID) // <--- here
                    .padding(0)
            }
            .onAppear {
                bundleID = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!.bundleIdentifier!
                print("\(#fileID):\(#line) - \(bundleID)")
            }
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
    }
}

struct XBContent: View {
    @Binding var bundleID: String  // <--- here
    @State private var data: String = ""  // <--- here

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(bundleID)
            Text(data)
        }
        .onAppear {
            data = bundleID  //  copy value
            print("\(#fileID):\(#line) - \(bundleID) | \(data)")
        }
    }
}

Since you have data = bundleID, these two values will always be the same.

That’s done it perfectly. I’m still trying to work out the bust use for the init() method.

let the View do what it does best, like init the State, Binding vars etc... don't try to roll your own, and AFAIK it is not recommended to do these things in init

I really appreciate the work you’ve put into answering my questions. I’m an experienced programmer, but SwiftUI is still voodoo to me. You help has enabled me to get over a few major speed humps, and get on with my project.

Yes, it can be a bit tricky at first. Note that you must understand @State and also @Binding to get anywhere in SwiftUI. And let the view do all the management of those.

If necessary, I’ll ask this is a separate question. Using @Binding did the job in this simple sample. However, I need to bind an object (for SwiftData), so I ended up using @Bindable instead. However it doesn’t work properly anymore, and I get a value that’s out of step again. Is there a simple trick, or would you like a more detailed sample?

ask a specific question and include the relevant code, especially the SwiftData components, how you declare the context and pass it to the views, where you have your @Query, and where you pass your object and how you use @Bindable, which is usually the correct approach. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78118769/problem-with-binding-a-swiftdata-model-property-to-a-toggle/78119568#78119568

When using SwiftData, your object is probably a @Model class (ie conforms to Observable), have you tried using just a var, eg var xBData: XBData without the @Bindable?
